# After site migration, only homepage loads

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I saw this mentioned before, but I couldn't find an answer.

I just migrated from my staging site to live, using a plug-in All in one WP migration. After a fresh install of wordpress + plugin on the new site, I took the .wpress file exported from staging and uploaded to the new.

Everything was successful, until I was redirected to the perma-links settings area to just save the final changes. However, from then any setting I touch in the perma-links section breaks my site. Any link in front end or back end will automatically download to browser.

After some digging, I found its related to the htaccess page. If you haven't already noticed, I'm new to this. I don't know where to start to test what could be wrong with the htaccess page, so I wiped it clean to at least be able to navigate the site.

Anytime I try to touch any permalinks setting in the backend, it will re-write in the faulty code and I have to go back into the wipe the htaccess again.

The second issue is it's causing any page (besides the homepage) to 404. If I try to preview a page from backend (mywebsite.com/page1) it 404's, and of course front end. Same if I try to create a new page.

Please let me know any other info I can provide. I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you don't have mod-rewrite on your live environment

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** export your database then open it in notpad++ then ctrl+f find your website old URL suppose stackoverflow.com/dev and replace it with your live site stackoverflow.com after replacing all URL make save it and make zip again.

**step 2** import the database into your site database.

**step 3** go to your dev site and download all setup with WordPress now paste the all files into new website directories.

**step 3** open wp-config.php file and changes database name username and password.

**step 4** open your wp-admin and use the username and password same which one you using for the dev site

**step 5** go to permalinks and set it %%postname%%

these are simple steps and I am sure it will work for you. no need to new WordPress installation.

Answer (score 0):

Could provide us with your .htaccess file?

But as someone noticed - problably you don't have mod_rewrite. Contact your hosting company, they should be able to fix your problem